# I want to get the different between two arrays

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have following two arrays: `$array1`, `$array`. I want the difference between these two arrays.
That is, how can I find the values that do not exist in second arrays?

```
$this->db->select('subject_id');
$this->db->where('section_id', $row['section_id']);
$this->db->where('day', $row['day']);

$progress = $this->db->get('class_routine')->result_array();
foreach ($progress as $key => $row3):

    $number1 = $row3['subject_id'];
    $array1 = explode(',', $number1);
    foreach ($array1 as $item1) {
        echo "<div style=\"color:#000;\">".$item1."</div>";
    }

endforeach;

$this->db->select('subject_id');
$this->db->where('section_id', $row['section_id']);
$this->db->where('day', $row['day']);
$progress = $this->db->get('progress')->result_array();
foreach ($progress as $row4):

    // echo $row4['subject_id'];

    $numbers = $row4['subject_id'];
    $array = explode(',', $numbers);
    foreach ($array as $items) {
        //echo $items;
        echo "<div style=\"color:red;\">".$items."</div>";

        $result = array_diff($array1, $array);

        echo "<div style=\"color:green;\">".$result."</div>";

    }

endforeach;

if($item1 != $items)
{
}  else {
    echo "All Present";
}
```

I have tried the following PHP function `array_diff` - it echos as 
following:

```
1
2
3
2
Array
3
Array
```

Comment: Arrays should be printed with `print_r`

Comment: i tried with print_r() this what i am getting  
1
2
3
2
Array ( )
3
Array ( ) All Present

Comment: yes i tried whats in the php manual

Comment: Can you post an example of what `$array1` and `$array` might look like?

Answer (score 2):

you should probably not loop `array_diff`. Try something more like this:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(....whatever goes in here....);
$array2 = array(....whatever goes in here....);
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);  //will return an array

print_r($result);
?>
```

Multiple occurrences in `$array1` are all treated the same way. This will output an array containing the differences.

You can get this kind of information from [php.net](http://php.net/)

source: [php.net/array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: thanks,i tried that one it didnt return the expected out

Comment: i am more confused about the place where i put the   $result = array_diff($array1, $array);

        echo "<div style=\"color:green;\">".$result."</div>";

Comment: I think you should not put `array_diff` in your loop, see updated my answer.

Comment: I tried as you suggested it worked for some extent but it always return the last value of array..lets say there are 3 values in the first array and 3 values in the last array it always return the last value

Comment: like this Array ( [0] => 1 )
1
Array ( [0] => 2 )
2
Array ( [0] => 3 )
3
3
3
All Present

Comment: well i tried that way ...is this beacuase first array foreach end before start of the second array? is this the reason always get the last value? like this Array ( [0] => 1 ) 1 Array ( [0] => 2 ) 2 Array ( [0] => 3 ) 3 3 3 All Present

Comment: if i tried like this                            $numbers = $row4['subject_id'];
                                            $array = explode(',', $numbers);
$result = array_diff($array1, $array);
foreach ($result as $items) {

    echo "<div style=\"color:green;\">".$items."</div>";

}

                                         endforeach;  
                                        endforeach;       results looks alike this Array ( [0] => 1 )
1
Array ( [0] => 2 )
2
2
All Present

Comment: The code from the `PHP` documentation answers your question. If you use it exactly like above you will get the difference between 2 arrays. How you want to display an array should be a different question or none at all.

Comment: @jowy : According to your second comment, I think your are using ```echo``` to print array, can you please try with ```print_r```?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in php.net

```
<?php
$array1    = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2    = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

It will show this

`Array
(
    [1] => blue
)`

Comment: yes this solution is fine for php but i am returning a code-igniter array